# Cleaner way to repeatedly call the same group of functions but with different parameters

Tags: performance, optimization, coding-style

Say you have code like this?

```
int main ()

function1();
function2(2);
function3(2);


function1();
function2(5);
function3(5);

function1();
function2(9);
function3(9);

function1();
function2(3);
function3(3);
```

would it make it cleaner to do something like this?

```
int main()
{
processFunctions(2);
processFunctions(5);
processFunctions(9);
processFunctions(3);
}
void processFunctions(int x)
{
function1();
function2(x);
function3(x);
}
```

And would it make a difference if instead of calling 3 functions its 2, 4 , or 5 functions?

NOTE: this part it just to fit the word requirement...
This part is to add more details, idk my code example it really straight forward I think?
Idk how many more details they want from me. yay I did it, I was able to fit the word requirements. The end

Comment: short answer: yes

Answer (score 0):

it really depends and readability should be priority

lets take a look for 2 different cases

```
int main() {
 getUserConfig();
 loadUserData();
 mapUserData();
}
```

this could be done by a function and be way more readable and less repetitive

```
getUserData() {
 getUserConfig();
 loadUserData();
 mapUserData();
}
```

and becomes

```
int main () {
 getUserData();
}
```

and a different one

```
int main() {
 randomPointCloud();
 getBoundingBox();
 getVolume();
}
```

in this case it could make sense to create another function, but depends on your use case